# What is the best way of accepting payments for listings using monero as payment, converted and paid into bank

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, payment-integration, fiat, integration

What is the best way to accept Monero as a payment for listings in small sums of $1 - $30 dollars? I will be selling listing space on a website, like a classifieds site. Most of the listings will be free, but some will be paid for depending on city and classification of listing and number of days.

So the customer should be able to pay online with Monero. The conversion should take place automatically, and I can either accept the Monero in my Android Monerujo wallet, or I may opt to have it converted into GBP and the balance put in my UK account.

I am not a coding expert, and I prefer a simple solution, the listings website will not be Wordpress, but it will be built with PHP and MYSQL database.

Any advice welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get Monero converted to fiat directly to your bank account, you'll want to check out https://globee.com/, which allows your users to pay in several cryptocurrencies and will pay you in your choice of fiat (you can also decide to keep some part of the income in monero if you wish).

Globee offers plugins for various website hosting software (https://globee.com/plugins) but also allows you to use their API directly should you decide to integrate it manually.

For small users, there is a "free" tier, though it will require a $10 minimum price (and will charge 1%, so not actually free, they have to earn somewhere). This might be a showstopper since you mention prices as low as $1.

If this doesn't meet your requirements, then maybe https://github.com/monero-integrations might help, though I think it's Monero only - no fiat conversion.

Comment: There are also some alternatives to GloBee listed at: https://web.getmonero.org/community/merchants/#payment-gateways